# Can you suggest me corrections to be made in this piece of android code?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

i want to read all sms from inbox and check for a particular keyword.I developed this code.but it doesn't produce the desired result.please suggest me corrections to be made.

```
    public void onClick(View arg0 ){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = content.query(uri,new String[] { "_id","address","body","person"}, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(c.moveToNext())
            {
                colName = colName + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")) + "\n";
                if(colName.contains("hai"))

                    textview1.setText("present");

                else
                    textview1.setText("not present");
            }
        }

    }
    });

}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't produce the desired result" means?

Comment: any error? post your logcat here

Comment: there are no errors or warnings. nothing is displayed when i run the application @imrankhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your questions is rather vague when it comes to supplied information this is just a guess:

If you have multiple SMS and one of them contains the word "hai", if this SMS is not the last one the resulting text will be "not present" since you are **overwriting** this textview in **every** iteration with the cursor.

So for example if you add a return after setting the textview to "present" you should be able to see the result "present" if the word is present in at least one SMS.

```
if(colName.contains("hai")){
      textview1.setText("present");
      return; 
}else{
      textview1.setText("not present");
}
```

Comment: I would just set the text to "not present" after you exit the loop to avoid setting it many times.

Comment: Yes of course :) Hopefully now that he knows what the probable faulty part is he will probably count the number of presences instead and do any UI alteration after the loop has finished.

Comment: thanks for your help.but now i am getting a error as  `[2012-12-03 00:33:25 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-12-03 00:33:25 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Rocker\.android\avd\2.1.avd/sdcard.img
[2012-12-03 00:33:25 - Emulator] ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Users\Rocker\.android\avd\2.1.avd/snapshots.img`

Comment: please can you help me with this error? the app is not running on any virtual device @NicklasGnejsEriksson

Comment: Not based on that warning sorry, try restarting your IDE and recreating the AVD. Or the best, stop using AVD, they suck, use a real device, much faster :)

Comment: thank you.i will try it.i just have another doubt.will this code read all inbox sms?

Comment: I have no clue, have never tried reading SMS, just saw a logical error in your loop :P